# How to train just first layer of a network?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have trained a network with two convolution layers and two dense. 
then for some reason I need to add another convolution layer as first layer of network, So I add a layer and freeze other layers, but as you see that in the below image no significant change were made in weights of this layer.

does any body have any idea why this happen? is this affect of vanishing gradient or something else?

[image: bias and weight change of added layer]

Comment: It's very hard to diagnose a problem we cannot reproduce.  Can you make a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that illustrates the problem?

Answer (score 0):

`tf.optimizer.minimize()`s accept `var_list` parameters, put the Variables you want to update in it will do as you expected.